# 'helicopter' tagged questions need improvement!

Tags: discussion, low-quality

I've been going through all the helicopter questions, and the quality of the answers is quite low, so I have been working to improve them:

https://aviation.stackexchange.com/search?tab=active&q=helicopter

There are issues with aerodynamics, operations, maneuvers, regulations, etc., etc.

Even questions which I have not answered anew, I have improved the accepted answer if I thought it was substantially correct, or have added a comment, such as: https://aviation.stackexchange.com/posts/8704/revisions

I'm assuming that not only are the answers written by non-copter drivers, but the upvotes are also from people who don't fly helis.

I would really like to improve the quality of these answers, and would like to enlist the help of the community to review and comment/edit/question all of my new answers and my comments so they make sense.

Answer (score 5):

This is not surprising: There are far fewer helicopter pilots than fixed wing pilots, so many of the helicopter answers are written by us fixed-wing guys, based on our limited understanding (and occasionally misunderstanding) of helicopter regs and operational principles.
As we get more helicopter guys like you around hopefully the quality of answers on helicopter questions will go up.

---

As far as reviewing the questions & getting new (better) answers upvoted, right now the most efficient ways to get eyeballs on questions/answers are to update them (editing an answer or posting a new one makes the question "active" and floats it up on the homepage for people using the ["Active" sort](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=active)) or to post them in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12036/the-hangar) where many of the regulars hang out.

Comment: please feel free to review and upvote!  http://aviation.stackexchange.com/search?tab=active&q=helicopter

Answer (score 0):

The answer you linked to is mine. In general I don't like to see my answers changed by others in a structural way (as you may have noticed before :-)), but in this case I think it adds valuable information (more than the OP asked for). I am happy to leave your addition in (I've improved the markup a bit)

Your assumption is correct, I don't drive helicopters, but I've done some hovering and landing practice and a few hours cruise flight. Big fun!

Answer (score 0):

We have another outbreak. [This question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/11709/how-do-helicopters-turn-using-rotor/11716#11716) is a real mess.  There is so much misinformation, misinterpretation and guesswork (plus perhaps a sprinkling of PC flight simulator experience) that is only possible to get correct and complete answers by carefully picking through the comments.

Perhaps we could ask all members to list their qualifications?